# Save a form on generated button click

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to insert form fields on a dynamically generated button event. The form is also generated dynamically. However, the submit event handler is not triggering.  Here is my code:

```
Protected Sub BindForm()
    'select query for fetching record from database
    'dynamically generated button

    Dim btnSubmit As New Button()
    btnSubmit.ID = "btnSubmit"
    btnSubmit.Text = "Save"
    AddHandler btnSubmit.Click, AddressOf Me.btnSubmit_click
    form1.Controls.Add(btnSubmit)

End Sub

' Dynamic button click event
Protected Sub btnSubmit_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
      Dim Query As String = "INSERT INTO table column values some_value"
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this Windows Forms, or…?

Comment: @Neolisk BindForm binds on page loads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create, add, and hookup the event in the `OnInit` method of the `Page`. After doing that it will bind the control on post back and fire the event.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(e As EventArgs)
    Dim btnSubmit As New Button()
    btnSubmit.ID = "btnSubmit"
    btnSubmit.Text = "Save"
    AddHandler btnSubmit.Click, AddressOf Me.btnSubmit_click
    form1.Controls.Add(btnSubmit)
End Sub 'OnInit
```

Comment: Perrenound, now by using above approach Submit Event is triggering but button generated before the Forms Bind.Which obviously not required.?My requirement is reserved to that..plz help